# Netflix conductor - Orkes or self managed?

Tags: conductor, netflix-conductor

Is anyone using Netflix conductor on production code? If yes are you using the managed version by Orkes or integrated and managing directly yourself?
Would like any insights here, as we are in confused on what to go with.

We tried a POC with integrating directly, but we were facing issues when using Postgres for persistence and other deployment related issues, and were unable to find a good community help while debugging the issue.

Answer (score 5):

[Netflix Conductor](https://github.com/Netflix/conductor) is used by a number of companies either using open source or Orkes.io.  Orkes is a [cloud hosted version](https://conductor.netflix.com/devguide/running/hosted.html#orkes) of Conductor by the creators and maintainers of the Netflix Conductor project.

Happy to help out if you have issues/questions running in the production just open up the issue on GitHub discussions.

Comment: Hey do you use the cloud hosted version or the open source self managed one?

Answer (score 0):

We are using Orkes as a managed solution.   What I have found in our organization is that the support and expertise of the Orkes team (paid for solution) is much more valuable to our software practice than hosting it or managing it ourselves.

Orkes to Conductor, is to me like RedHat is to Linux.    You can use the OpenSource version very well, but if you need enterprise capabilities, then you can go with the supported version, i.e. Orkes.